# Error Handling when using Redis Bulk Import

Tags: redis, redis-cli, bulk-import

I'm using redis-cli to do some bulk importing 800mil keys transfer. When I use it if some command was not able to execute for some reason how do I know which command failed the output won't say which command failed so that I can retry etc. Any thoughts on how to get proper outputs?

```
cat file.txt | redis-cli --pipe
```

Sharing sample output that I created by making OOM intentionally

```
OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'.
OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'.
OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'.
OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'.
OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'.
```

I tried searching Documentation but its no good